# iPhone: How to copy a file from resources to documents?

Tags: iphone

I just started with iPhone development. In one of the example where I had to display some data stored in sqlite db in a table view in a tabbar controller, I had to move a sqlite file from application bundle to the documents folder.

I used the application template - iOS > Application > Window-based application for iPhone (Used core data for storage)

In the template generated by XCode (base sdk set to latest iOS = 4.2), the following code was there...

```
- (NSURL *)applicationDocumentsDirectory {
    return [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
}
```

In trying to get a path to documents folder, I used the method given above like this...

```
NSString *documentDirectory = [self applicationDocumentsDirectory];
```

This gave a warning - `warning: incompatible Objective-C types initializing 'struct NSURL *', expected 'struct NSString *'`

So I changed the code to following...

```
// Added the message absoluteString over here
NSString *documentDirectory = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] absoluteString];

NSString *writableDBPath = [documentDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"mydb.sqlite"];
NSString *defaultDBPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"mydb.sqlite"];
BOOL success = [fileManager copyItemAtPath:defaultDBPath toPath:writableDBPath error:&error];
if (!success) {
   NSLog(@"Failed to create writable database file with message '%@'.", [error localizedDescription]);
}
```

And BOOM!!! It gave the error that - `'Failed to create writable database file with message 'The operation couldn’t be completed. No such file or directory'.'`

How should I find the path to documents directory since the method `applicationDocumentsDirectory` generated by XCode template does not work for me.

Also, can somebody throw some light on the purpose of `applicationDocumentsDirectory` method given above.

Thanks

Comment: I was getting error because i was not adding the file name on the writableDBPath. This example helped me fixing it. Thanks! +1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just ran into this myself a few days ago. Don't force things down the Path path, embrace the NSURL path. It won't take but a short time to get how to use them.

As to the method, it's simply asking the system to hand you a URL to the standardized documents directory for the application. Use this and most everything regarding where you put new files will be correct.

Comment: more details on this please? :(

Answer (score 20):

heres a simple way to do it:

```
    NSFileManager *fmngr = [[NSFileManager alloc] init];
    NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"mydb.sqlite" ofType:nil];
    NSError *error;
    if(![fmngr copyItemAtPath:filePath toPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/Documents/mydb.sqlite", NSHomeDirectory()] error:&error]) {
         // handle the error
         NSLog(@"Error creating the database: %@", [error description]);

    }
    [fmngr release];
```

Comment: Rich you're right but a little out of date. From the current docs: "This will always return the same instance of the file manager. The returned object is not thread safe.

In Mac OS X v 10.5 and later you should consider using [[NSFileManager alloc] init] rather than the singleton method defaultManager. Using [[NSFileManager alloc] init] instead, the resulting NSFileManager instance is thread safe."

Comment: So, I'd make a couple of small changes to the above: I'd change the first line's RHS to [[NSFileManager alloc] init], and I'd add [fmngr release]; after the if block.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I now remember reading that when 4.0 came out, but I guess I just crammed it to the back of my head learning about all the other updates.