# Upgrade an app with new data in core data

Tags: ios, core-data, upgrade

I have a problem in upgrading my app live in App Store.
This app has a core data database with 100 records. In my new version, I want to upload a new database with the same schema, but with 101 records and I want that when the user updates the app, the new data are displayed.

From my understanding, if I simply update data in core data, the old database is maintained  and the only way to access to the new data is to unistall the app and install it again.

Do you have any suggestions to force the installed app on the phone to use the new core data after the upgrade?

Answer (score 0):

Does the app have a sqlite file part of the bundle?  If so you can just check how many rows are in core data.  If 100, then copy the new sqlite file from the bundle to the Documents directory.  [This link might help.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4743317/iphone-how-to-copy-a-file-from-resources-to-documents)

Comment: And what about if the user changed some values in a table of core data and I want to merge my modifications and those from the user?

Imagine the user saved his favorites in the respective table in core data. And Imagine that I want to update values in other tables.
Any ideas???

Comment: You can have more than one NSManagedObjectContext objects.  Create an additional NSManagedObject for your default sqlite file in your bundle.  For each item in your default sqlite file, check if the user has modified it.  If they have, then skip to the next.  If not, replace the values.  If the item does not exist you can add it.

Comment: I can't get rid of this problem. As a workaround I included in my bundle a new database with a different name, so the first time it will be installed and used instead of the older one. But I know that in this way, I'll lost the records modified from the user.
From my understanding of your suggestion, I have to insert in my bundle the new and the old databases, and update the new one with modified records of the second. You say I've to use two different Context... but how? Do you have some examples or tutorials? Thanks in advance!!

Comment: You app delegate already contains an example of how to create a NSManagedObjectContext.  Just alloc another one to a different variable.  You'll need a different NSPersistentStoreCoordinator too.  I might suggest to create a NSObject to manage the second Core Data stack as well as merging the original sqlite file and the new one in your bundle.

Comment: Create a new class derived from NSObject.  Copy the Core Data stack code from your app delegate.  Rename the sqlite file, use the same NSManagedObjectModel.  Done.  To merge, also pass in the NSManagedObjectContext from the app delegate that contains the users modifications, fetch all the records in one and search for them in the other however that works out best.