# iOS sqlite cannot commit, no transaction is active

Tags: ios, sqlite

I am doing a button on iOS to update SQlite data. I am able to update the value using Firefox SQLite Manager, but having the issue of "cannot commit, no transaction is active" using the code below. Please shed some light. Thanks.

=
- (id *)updateBanks{

```
sqlite3_stmt *statement = NULL;

const char *branch_no = "MAYBANK1";
const char *address = "KLCC";

NSFileManager *fileMgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

NSString *dbPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath ]stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"banks.sqlite"];

BOOL success = [fileMgr fileExistsAtPath:dbPath];

if(!success)
{
    NSLog(@"Cannot locate database file '%@'.", dbPath);
}
if(!(sqlite3_open([dbPath UTF8String], &db) == SQLITE_OK))
{
    NSLog(@"An error has occured.");

}

    if(sqlite3_open([dbPath UTF8String], &db) == SQLITE_OK)
{
    const char *sql = "Update Maybank Set address = ? Where branch_no = ?";
    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, sql, -1, &statement, NULL)==SQLITE_OK){
        sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 1, address, -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
        //sqlite3_bind_text(updateStmt, 1, [address.text UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
        sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 2, branch_no, -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);


    }
}
char* errmsg;
sqlite3_exec(db, "COMMIT", NULL, NULL, &errmsg);

if(SQLITE_DONE != sqlite3_step(statement)){
    NSLog(@"Error while updating. %s", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
}
else{

}
sqlite3_finalize(statement);
sqlite3_close(db);
return 0;
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_transaction.html) says:

> Any command that changes the database (basically, any SQL command other than SELECT) will automatically start a transaction if one is not already in effect. Automatically started transactions are committed when the last query finishes.
>
> Transactions can be started manually using the BEGIN command. Such transactions usually persist until the next COMMIT or ROLLBACK command.

So the automatic transaction of your UPDATE statement already has been commited.
You need to run COMMIT only if you've also run BEGIN.

---

Also, you must not call `sqlite3_open` twice; the first database connection will be leaked.

Also, you would have to call `sqlite3_step` and `sqlite3_finalize` *before* executing the COMMIT.

Also, resources are read only; you have to [copy the database file out of the bundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4743317/iphone-how-to-copy-a-file-from-resources-to-documents) to be able to modify it.

Comment: Also to add to this, the SQLite file in the Main bundle, which is readonly so any UPDATE, INSERT and DELETE will fail.